# How do modern browsers implement JS Array, specifically adding elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

By this I mean when calling `.push()` on an Array object and JavaScript increases the capacity (in number of elements) of the underlying "array". Also, if there is a good resource for finding this sort of information for JS, that would be helpful to include.

**edit**

It seems that the JS Array is like an object literal with special properties. However, I'm interested in a lower level of detail--how browsers implement this in their respective JS engines.

Comment: what do you mean by capacity? size in bytes?

Comment: I imagine it depends on the implementation. I don't think it's specified that it has to be done in a certain way...

Comment: @jswolf19 I kind of assumed that nobody like w3c or Ecma has specified an implementation, but surely there are implementations, e.g. for webkit.

Comment: @Jeff, what is "the" algorithm is different from "what algorithims do different engines use". the second, what you're really asking, is a much better question.

Comment: @Samuel Neff Are you saying that I can't ask about the implementation of the abstraction that is "the JS Language?" My reading of "the implementation" would be "the implementation of the major browsers." But point well taken.  I'll be more specific in the future :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There cannot be any single correct answer to this qurstion. An array's mechanism for expanding is an internal implementation detail and can vary from one JS implementation to another. In fact, the Tamarin engine has two different implementations used internally for arrays depending on if it determines if the array is going to be sequential or sparse.

Comment: +1, I'd give you more if I could I don't often learn anything new about JS :)  Apparently both Chrome & FF use similar implementations (both a vector & a hash, or similar) as can be inferred from benchmarks: http://jsperf.com/array-popuplation-direction

Comment: @Samuel Neff This is really interesting.  How do you find out how different browsers (their respective JS engines) work at this level?

Comment: An interesting article on this subject: http://news.qooxdoo.org/javascript-array-performance-oddities-characteristics

Answer (score 1):

This answer is wrong.  Please see @Samuel Neff's answer and the following resources:

http://news.qooxdoo.org/javascript-array-performance-oddities-characteristics

http://jsperf.com/array-popuplation-direction

Arrays in JavaScript don't have a capacity since they aren't real arrays.  They're actually just object hashes with a `length` property and properties of `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`, etc.  When you do `.push()` on an array, it effectively does:

```
ary[ ary.length++ ] = the_new_element; // set via hash
```

Comment: You can leave off the `++` on `ary.length`.

Comment: @Reid - no, you can't.  The ++ is to increment array.length, not to use while setting the value (I was referring to what was happening inside the engine, not to actual JS code)

Comment: @cwolves, your description of an Array object in Javascript is not wrong at all, they are simple objects as you say, with some special characteristics -like their `length` property-, they inherit from `Array.prototype` and their `[[Class]]` internal property is `"Array"`, e.g. `({}).toString.call([]); // "[object Array]"`, but yes, the internals of memory management are completely *implementation dependent*.

Comment: @CMS - I realize that, but as far as answering the question goes, my answer is wrong.  The question is asking about the sub-js-api level implementation of Array.

Comment: @cwolves: ah, I see. I thought you were talking about equivalent JS, not what was inside the engine. :P

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does include a mechanism to declare the length of your array like:

```
var foo = new Array(3);
alert(foo.length); // alerts 3
```

But since arrays are dynamic in javascript there is no reason to do this, you don't have to manually allocate your arrays.  The above example does not create a fixed length array, just initializes it with 3 undefined elements.

// Edit: I either misread your question or you changed it, sorry I don't think this is what you were asking.

Comment: Helpful info, but it's not correct to say there is no reason to do this. It's very possible that initializing an array to a known future length will make adding to it later more efficient. It entirely depends on the individual browser's implementation, but may be a big performance improvement depending on the implementation.